# Refresh page just once after getting response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, window.location

I am trying to reload the page after getting the response. But the issue I am facing is that it page reload goes into a loop and reloads continuously. How can I make it reload just once after getting the response.

create.vue

```
<script>
export default {
 data () {
    return {
      agent: {
        full_name: '',
        address: '',
      }
    }
 }
 created() {
    this.fetchAgent();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchAgent() {
      this.$axios.get(`/agent.json?${this.$route.query()}`)
          .then(response => {
            this.agent = response.data;
            window.location.reload();
          });
    },
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That value is only being stored in memory and will not be present after a page refresh. Can you explain more closely what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you want to refresh a page?

Comment: @RossAllen Actually after the fetchAgent method runs, the agent is suppose to login but it doesnt. but if I refresh the page the it shows as logged in.